# Squid ncsa_auth authentication and user groups

Tags: squid, ncsa

I have two kinds of users accessing squid. I want the first group can access always internet, the second should only be allowed to access internet at certain times.

I have users on the same file (created with htpasswd).

How can achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to set up authentication

Add the following to the authentication section of your squid.conf

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth /usr/local/etc/squid/passwd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 8 hours
```

You will want to change the path to the password file to match your password file location. You may want to change the `credentialsttl` if you want people to authenticate more frequently.

In the a ACL section of your squid.conf add the following

```
acl allowed_anytime proxy_auth "/usr/local/etc/squid/allowed_anytime"
acl allowed_by_time proxy_auth "/usr/local/etc/squid/allowed_by_time"

acl allow_hours time SMTWHFA 09:00-17:00

http_access allow  allowed_anytime

http_access allow allowed_by_time allow_hours

http_access deny all
```

You may want to create your `allowed_anytime` and `allowed_by_time` elsewhere so change the paths above.

The file `allowed_anytime` should contain a list of users who can use the internet all the time e.g.

```
user1
user2
user3
...
```

The file `allowed_by_time` should contain a list of users who can use the internet during the time specified by the `allow_hours` acl e.g.

```
user4
user5
user6
user7
...
```